# Why MySQL is very slow when using JOIN instead of WHERE?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, where-clause

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_sample` (
  `idtest_sample` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `test_samplecol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idtest_sample_UNIQUE` (`idtest_sample`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `idnew_table` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idnew_table_UNIQUE` (`idnew_table`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The first table contains 5 million records while the second one only 10 records.

The duration of the execution of this query is more than 5 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM test_sample 
INNER JOIN new_table 
ON test_sample.idtest_sample = new_table.idnew_table
```

while this query is executed immediately (less than 0.001 second):

```
SELECT * FROM test_sample 
WHERE test_sample.idtest_sample IN 
('3','1597','25963','170596','196485',
'545963','999999','1265896','1569485','1999999')
```

Why the first query takes so long?

Comment: what if you try `SELECT test_sample.* FROM ...` your first query?

Comment: Run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on both queries.

Comment: Is it even if 2nd table has a good index?

Comment: Both tables have index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to see the execution path ? DESC {SQL}, your first one is certainly longer

The first query certainly look the entire 5 millions rows for each row of the other table.
While your second query only look for specific ID which have an index (as they're part of primary key)

Edit:
Here are your EXPLAIN (simplified):

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys        | key  |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | new_table   | system | idnew_table_UNIQUE   | NULL |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_sample | ALL    | idtest_sample_UNIQUE | NULL |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+------+
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys        | key                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_sample | const | idtest_sample_UNIQUE | idtest_sample_UNIQUE |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see there is an 'ALL' scan on the test_sample table (5 millions line)

You may want to take a look here : http://hackmysql.com/case4

Comment: So, is it possible in MySQL to use JOIN that doesn't look the entire table but only the specific IDs?

Answer (score 1):

first query will take more time because it check each row of another table for 5 millions record. on the other hand second sql have certain indexed column.
Hope it will help you.